# Acrobat Javascript - How to make user only use 3 out 4 text fields (no matter which 3)?

Tags: javascript, acrobat

I have a group of 4 text fields but only want to allow user to fill in 3 of them (at user's choice) and if user tries to fill in the fourth, don't allow.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Without exact field names, I can't give you exact code but here's how to achieve what you want. For each of the 4 fields, in the "On Blur" event, check the value of each field, if three fields have a non-blank value, set the 4th to read-only.

By performing the calculation in "On Blur" you'll be checking the value of the fields after a new value has been entered.

Comment: Hi Joel, using text1, text2, text3 and text4 as field names, do you have any suggestion for the code? Thanks